# Why update trigger is making rounding in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, triggers, sql-update

I have a price of one item is 1.5750 in table called 'Item', whenever the price will change it will update to another table

This is my update trigger

```
update Ss
    set price = cast( i.Price * 100 as int)
    from    Updateitems ss
    
    inner join inserted i on i.ItemNo = ss.ItemNo
```

In item table the price will be 1.5750

After it update, the price is showing **158** on `UpdateItem` Table.

But when I execute query directly like this `select cast( 1.5750 * 100 as int)`
the output is showing **157**

Why it is updating 158?

which one is correct?

**Note:**

> Price datatype is money on `item` table
>
> price datatype is varchar in `Updateitems` table

Comment: Column i.Price data type?

Comment: @jarlh can you please check my update?

Comment: Try `select cast(cast(1.5750 as money) * 100 as int) ...`

Comment: BTW, why do you have different data types for the price columns?

Comment: @jarlh please wait bro. I will check

Comment: @jarlh bro still same. no changes. It becomes

Answer (score 0):

*"If SQL Server performs calculations on the MONEY datatype, intermediate values are stored internally as MONEY datatypes. **Since MONEY only represents four places to the right of the decimal, any calculation requiring 5 or more places in the fractional representation will incur roundoff error.**"*

[Source](https://blog.learningtree.com/is-money-bad-the-money-datatype-in-sql-server/)

**Change your update to following if you can't change the datatype.**

```
update Ss
    set price = cast( cast(@Price as float) * 100 as int)
    from    Updateitems ss

    inner join inserted i on i.ItemNo = ss.ItemNo
```

Comment: i don't want to be float

Comment: You shouldn't use float if you want an *accurate decimal datatype*, which most people do tend to like to use when dealing with currencies. You should use `decimal` with appropriate selections for precision and scale.

Comment: @Liamneesan Ideally you should change your datatype

Answer (score 0):

You are taking your decimal value of 1.5750 and multiplying it by 100, that is correct, which gives 157.50, but then you are casting it to an `int` data type, integer data types, can only hold whole number values so when they are given a decimal value they round to (usually) the nearest whole number, which is why you see it come back as 158.

If you want to keep the decimal values you can cast it as a decimal instead;

`select cast( 1.5750 * 100 as decimal(5,2))`

`decimal(5,2)` allows you to have 2 numbers after the decimal point (usual for money values), and still keep your 3 numbers before it.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting the value to INT, which eventually gives you **157**

```
SELECT cast( cast(@Price as float) * 100 as decimal(5,2))
```